# Error while using VNDetectRectanglesRequest and CameraPreview CVPixelBuffer in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have been stuck on a problem for a few days.

Our CameraPreview works perfectly, along with the VNDetectRectanglesRequest.
Once we move over a rectangle our Handler is called, which makes me believe the CVPixelBuffer is passing a valid image into the processor.

When the handler is called we request GetResults and get the exception:

```
[0:] Rectangle Observations Exception - Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSRangeException Reason: *** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4354863128 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]
```

I can obviously tell that this is related to an array however I have a working copy using: UIImagePickerController which is working perfectly within a simulator, but moving the code over to a live preview is having issues.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Here is my code snippet:

```
    public class VisionDocumentDecoder : DefaultDecoderBase
    {
        private TaskCompletionSource<DocumentScanResult> documentResult = null;

        private VNDetectRectanglesRequest documentRequest;
        private UIImageOrientation orientation = UIImageOrientation.Down;

        public VisionDocumentDecoder() : base()
        {
            documentRequest = new VNDetectRectanglesRequest(OnImageRectangleHandled);
            //documentRequest.MaximumObservations = 6;
            //documentRequest.MinimumConfidence = 0.1f;
            //documentRequest.MinimumAspectRatio = 0.3f;
            //documentRequest.QuadratureTolerance = 75;
        }

        public UIImage Convert(CVPixelBuffer pixelBuffer)
        {
            CIImage ciImage = CIImage.FromImageBuffer(pixelBuffer);

            CIContext temporaryContext = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
            using (CGImage cgImage = temporaryContext.CreateCGImage(ciImage, new CGRect(0, 0, pixelBuffer.Width, pixelBuffer.Height)))
            {
                UIImage uiImage = UIImage.FromImage(cgImage);
                return uiImage;
            }
        }

        public override IScanResult Decode(CVPixelBuffer pixelBuffer)
        {
            Logger.Log("Decoding sample ...");

            documentResult = new TaskCompletionSource<DocumentScanResult>();

            CIImage ciImage = CIImage.FromImageBuffer(pixelBuffer);
            UIImage image = Convert(pixelBuffer);
            if (image == null)
            {
                documentResult.SetResult(null);
                return documentResult.Task.Result;
            }
            var handler = new VNImageRequestHandler(image.CGImage,
                ConvertToCGImagePropertyOrientation(image.Orientation), new NSDictionary());

            DispatchQueue.DefaultGlobalQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
            {
                handler.Perform(new VNRequest[]
                {
                        documentRequest
                }, out NSError error);
            });

            documentResult.Task.Wait();

            return documentResult.Task.Result;
        }


        void OnImageRectangleHandled(VNRequest request, NSError error)
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                documentResult.SetException(new NSErrorException(error));
                return;
            }

            Logger.Log("Rectangle image handler");

            var decoder = PerformanceCounter.Start();
            var scanResults = new DocumentScanResult();
            var documentResults = new List<DocumentPointResults>();

            scanResults.Success = true;

            try
            {
                Logger.Log($"Taking observations ...");

                var observations = request.GetResults<VNRectangleObservation>();
                //request.
                //var observations = request.GetResults<VNRectangleObservation>();
                Logger.Log($"Rectangles found {observations.Length}");

                if (observations.Length > 0)
                {
                    Logger.Log($"Rectangles found {observations.Length}");



                    //    foreach (var obs in observations)
                    //    {
                    //        Logger.Log("Found observation!");

                    //        var boundingBox = obs.BoundingBox;

                    //        var topLeft = new Point((int)boundingBox.X, (int)boundingBox.Y);
                    //        var topRight = new Point((int)boundingBox.X + (int)boundingBox.Width, (int)boundingBox.Y);

                    //        var bottomLeft = new Point((int)boundingBox.X, (int)boundingBox.Y + (int)boundingBox.Height);
                    //        var bottomRight = new Point((int)boundingBox.X + (int)boundingBox.Width, (int)boundingBox.Y + (int)boundingBox.Height);

                    //        documentResults.Add(new DocumentPointResults(topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight));
                    //    }


                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Log($"Rectangle Observations Exception - {e.Message}");
            }



            PerformanceCounter.Stop(decoder, "Vision document rectangle handler take {0} ms.");

            scanResults.Points = documentResults;
            documentResult.SetResult(scanResults);
        }

        //public override void ScanningOptionsUpdate(ScanningOptionsBase options)
        //{

        //}

        CGImagePropertyOrientation ConvertToCGImagePropertyOrientation(UIImageOrientation orientation)
        {
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case UIImageOrientation.Up:
                    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.Up;
                case UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored:
                    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.UpMirrored;
                case UIImageOrientation.Down:
                    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.Down;
                case UIImageOrientation.DownMirrored:
                    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.DownMirrored;
                case UIImageOrientation.Left:
                    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.Left;
                case UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored:
                    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.LeftMirrored;
                case UIImageOrientation.Right:
                    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.Right;
                case UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored:
                    return CGImagePropertyOrientation.RightMirrored;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("unrecognized orientation");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can add an [all-exception breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022#add-conditions-to-an-exception) to find which line cause the error.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I do have a breakpoint and it's caused when I call request.GetResults. I mentioned this in my question :)

Comment: Sorry, it's my carelessness. The error meaned you were trying to access an object which is not in the index of array. Had you checked the VNRectangleObservation?

Comment: Not a problem, I appreciate you messaging me, and all the help MSFT always provides. I love your guy's team and am friends with your leads. Yes, the same code is working when I am using the IPhotoPickerService on iOS, but not when using the callback for the AVCamera's and the CVPixelBuffer data, which I have tried to use directly, and change it to images to see if it's getting back the right data, and I see that they (CIImage and UIImage) are both processing the CVPixelBuffer data correctly.

Comment: In the handler if I set a breakpoint, request has a Count but I can't access it's properties without type-casting, which as you know is where the:
var observations = request.GetResults<VNRectangleObservation>();

Is what should return the correct type and allow us to make the properties visible. While results has a count, request.GetResults however fails. I have also tried to use both methods of casting without luck to access request.

Comment: The error ONLY fires off when a rectangle is detected, but works perfectly otherwise, and the same code I have checked multiple times, and have rewrote it -- it's pretty simple, and not sure really what to do as we are using a high-level programming language right ... so sometime's it's hard to find a problem laying deep inside a framework of someone elses, but again, it works with IPhotoPicker that returns the same CVPixelBuffer...

Comment: I don't understand how it is bounds[0..0], when, I hover and see a count of 1, but also don't know where it's coming up with index 4354863128, which is huge.... 

I had documentRequest.MaximumObservations = 6; set previously and commented it out, so the highest possibly index should have been 6, but it was still the large number. I definately don't have that many rectangles! lol

Comment: @Liyun Zhang - I have checked VNRequest and see objects of  type VNRectangleObservations in the Results property, when I run GetResults to convert the objects to VNRectangleObservations, it causes the crash.

When using the IPhotoPicker using iOS Native picker but loading from a file worked previously, so I tried to save the image as well, and then run the detector on that instead of directly on the NSData and still received the error. It seems related to the GetResults being in the callback of Decode(). 

I can provide a sample project privately if you have LinkedIn.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/stephanshere?_l=en_US